# Does the "Rapier Training" Swashbuckler class feature count as having the Improved Critical feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, archetype

I'm DMing for a group of five people. One player, Swashbuckler with the Inspired Blade archetype, wanted to select critical feats which have Improved Critical as a prerequisite. The following Inspired Blade feature describes it as follows:

> Rapier Training (Ex): At 5th level, an inspired blade gains a +1 bonus on attack rolls and a +2 bonus on damage rolls with rapiers. **While wielding a rapier, she gains the benefit of the Improved Critical feat.** These attack and damage bonuses increase by 1 for every 4 levels beyond 5th (to a maximum of +4 on attack rolls and +5 on damage rolls at 17th level). This ability replaces swashbuckler weapon training.

It seems to me that the player cannot do it, but I've house ruled otherwise. The reason is because his character looks pretty bad in the game (I did not tell him this) and is already getting behind others on the table. Charmed Life with Opportune Parry and Riposte are letting his immediate actions overloaded whilst his char is too squishy due to spending ability points on Dex, Int and Cha. Taxing him another feat with improved critical seemed bad from a balancing perspective. There is a vanilla warrior on the group who does everything the swashbuckler does but significantly better.

That being said I've got two questions for you:

1. Does the "Rapier Training" Swashbuckler class feature count as having the Improved Critical feat? (From the title)
2. What would you have done in such situation?

Obs.: this class seems quite unbalanced and badly designed to me.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that your question is the same as [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55413/23750) but with different class.
(And to answer your second part, I would have done the same, as it's more fun for everyone)

Comment: That's pretty much it. Thanks

Comment: If you want instead an evaluation of the swashbuckler class, the site can do that—a question like *Is the swashbuckler balanced compared to other primarily martial base and core classes?* (with a list of your concerns) should be in the site's wheelhouse. Likewise, a question like *How can this underperforming swashbuckler contribute more to this party?* (with details about the PC and the party, of course) should be valid. (Honestly, reading only a little between the lines, it sounds like one feat's not gonna help that swashbuckler much!)

Comment: Has pathfinder changed the rules about feats-as-requirements from 3.x?  Back in 3.x, Swashbuckler as written above would have given you the feat while you held the blade ("qualify for prerequisites" being one of the benefits), and you could easily enough take the things that had that prerequisite while in that state.